# Error with creating EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, jpa, junit4

I have a test. I am trying to test my Facade with JUnit4. I created FacadeTest :

```
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
private EntityManager em;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();     
}
```

I got an exception :
    [junit] Caused an ERROR
    [junit] javax/persistence/Persistence
    [junit] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence

I have hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final in classpath. 
Anybody can explain what is going on?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: jar files can be opened in your favorite zip tool as .zip files.  My suggestion for solving this would be to open up the jar you think your class should be declared in and see if the class is actually present.  At a guess, I'd say you're missing the javax.persistence jar, which hibernate depends on for it's implementation of the standard

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?